# DATEDIFF command won't work as 'day' is not a recognised column

Tags: sql, datediff

I'm relatively new to SQL and have been attempting to run a script wherein I can bring up the number of days that have passed between two points in time. I understand how this should look based on your website, but for some reason when I input the values, my database is returning the following error:

ProgrammingError: ERROR:  column "day" does not exist

The code I'm using is:

```
select datediff(day, '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01')
```

I assume I'm missing something very simple (this is a hugely basic query I'm sure), but would be appreciative of any assistance. I've variously tried pointing it towards the specific table I want to draw from, but it keeps stumbling on this error.

Comment: It's a postgreSQL database with Python used as the coding language. I'm not sure I can be much more specific than that, but it's a fairly old version of both softwares: 8.2 for Postgres and 2.4 for Python. Is that what you're looking for? Apologies if not...

Comment: See [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) looks like PostgreSQL doesn't support `datediff`.

Comment: That must be it, thanks very much - the link you've provided outlines a better way of proceeding with this in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in postgresql then use

```
select DATE_PART('day', '2014-01-01'::timestamp -  '2014-02-01'::timestamp)
```