# HOW to find the avg difference in order time in SQL

Tags: sql, mode-analytics

the dataset of subquery is here

```
id   itm_id   paid_at          ord_r total_r
17  3266    2013-05-25 08:27:17 1   3
17  3219    2013-05-25 08:27:17 2   3
17  3964    2013-05-25 08:27:17 3   3
25  2105    2013-05-17 03:11:48 1   2
25  1376    2013-05-17 03:11:48 2   2
63  2140    2013-07-07 11:26:45 1   3
```

### the code is here

for find out the average difference in order time, BUt i looked up here, and i found this piece of code
But i didn't understand why i use `(toatl-1)` 
if someone kindly explain the process
`i am doing this on mode analytics i don't know which machine it use, whether mysql or sqlserver`

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  item_id,
  CASE WHEN total_order-1 > 0
  THEN datediff(day, max(paid_at), min(paid_at))/ (total_order-1)
  ELSE datediff(day, max(paid_at), min(paid_at)) END AS avg_time
  FROM

(SELECT  
  user_id,
  item_id,
  paid_at,
  ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER by paid_at ASC) AS order_rank,
  COUNT(item_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY paid_at ASC) AS total_order
from 
  dsv1069.orders) user_level
```

But the problems is
`ERROR: column "day" does not exist`

Comment: seems like mysql, since there datediff has only the date parameters

Comment: Or maybe a PostgreSQL database? Similar error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712165/datediff-command-wont-work-as-day-is-not-a-recognised-column

Comment: Please tag the question with the DBMS you are using